# How to go back or forward in a array of questions?

Tags: ios, swift

I have an array of questions that are keys in a dictionary. The corresponding choices to each question are the value of each key. I want to the user to be able to skip or go back a question for navigational reasons if the user decides to want to skip a question or go back a question. Here is my swift code:

```
       @IBAction func goNext(_ sender: Any) {
}

func nextQ(sender: UIButton) {
    if sender == nextButton {
        questionTitle.text = surveyQuestions[1]
    }
}



var surveyQuestions = [String]()

func startSurvey() {
    
    if surveyQuestions.isEmpty {
        surveyQuestions = Array(SampleSurvey().surveyquestions.keys)
        print(surveyQuestions)
    }
    
    let rand = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(surveyQuestions.count)))
    questionTitle.text = surveyQuestions[rand]
    
    var choices = SampleSurvey().surveyquestions[surveyQuestions[rand]]!
    print(choices)
    print(choices.count)
    print(surveyChoices.count)
    surveyQuestions.remove(at: rand)

  }
```

The IBAction is the "skip" button. I want it to be function as follows: the button is pressed and the next question in the array is presented in to the user. I also want the user to be able to go back and have the previous question presented to them again along with the corresponding values/choices. How could I achieve this desired functionality?

Here is a screenshot of my current functionality, when I click the back or next in the bottom portion of the screen nothing happens. I want a new question to either be presented by clicking next or an old question to be presented by clicking back along with the corresponding choices

[image: screenshot]

Comment: OK. Could you give an example in code? I get what you are saying but would appreciate a visual explanation.

Comment: Also just a small tip, you should change `let rand = 
 Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(surveyQuestions.count)))` to `let rand = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(surveyQuestions.count - 1)))` to avoid index out of range issues.